# Function working on selector without erasing previous value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing a filtering function and get a bit stuck on this one.

**How can I combine the filter without undo the previous one ?**

[image]

### jQuery for beter understanding :

```
$('#departureCitys').change( function() {
    $('.products_dispo').each(function () {
            $(this).show();
            if($(this).find('.cityName').text() != $('#departureCitys').find(":selected").text()){
                 $(this).toggle();
                 }
    });
});

$('#departureDates').change( function() {
    $('.products_dispo').each(function () {
            $(this).show();
            if($(this).find('.departureDate').text() != $('#departureDates').find(":selected").text()){
                 $(this).toggle();
                 }
    });
});
```

Shall I change my way of doing ? The only solution I see is to do a switch but it will be horribly long (because I have more than two Select).

I've done a Fiddle but he is not working properly and I dont get why. 
Anyway if this can help you to understand... here is it --> [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Baldrani/DTcHh/10115/)

If anyone has an indication for me I'll be glad to look it out !

Comment: Can you provide some of the HTML code so we can better understand your question and what exactly the ids and classes are pointing to?

Comment: Yeah all right I can give you example. I'll do a Fiddle

Comment: Why don't you just handle the `change` event for each of the select elements and analyze *all* selections and hide/show based on that?  That should get you the "multi predicate" behavior that you're looking for.

Comment: Because I will have to hide some of the one who should be shown. I'll erase previous datas (I think..; I've tried and it was not fructif

Comment: @ctwheels I've Done one (and edited my question) but he is not working as expected as you will see... Stil than can help you understand my problem; I hope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change your code a bit and use the following. Basically what I've done is I've set a data attribute for each of the selection options, and then set concatenated data attributes (matching the content to the selected options) as a new data attribute on the table rows in the table.

So for example:

- 0 points to A, 1 points to B, 2 points to C, ... for destination city
- 0 points to 01/01/2015, 1 points to 02/01/2015, 2 points to 03/01/2015, ... for destination date
- 0 points to 1, 1 points to 2, 2 points to 3, ... for destination duration

And when (let's say) the following are selected: A, 01/01/2015, 5, the values would be 0, 0, 4. We then take these values and concatenate them into a new data value that we compare to the values in the table: `'0,0,4'` is compared to each table row's data attribute.

Where this gets 'tricky' is where multiple values are possible since nothing has been chosen for that selection. Let's say they leave destination date blank and have set destination city to A and destination duration to 5.

What the code below does is it uses Regex to compare the string to the output regex (created based on values selected by user, and if no selection is made, we default to `[0-9]+` which says + (one of more) of the following digits [0-9] (from 0 to 9)

In the case where the destination date is not selected, the output regex would be `/0,[0-9]+,4/`

Now all you need to do is use the primary key stored in the SQL database (as I suppose you are using to populate the fields with) and use that as the `data-id` values.

---

HTML

```
<table id='trips'>
    <thead>
        <th>
            <select class='departureCity'>
                <option></option>
                <option data-id='0'>A</option>
                <option data-id='1'>B</option>
                <option data-id='2'>C</option>
                <option data-id='3'>D</option>
                <option data-id='4'>E</option>
            </select>
        </th>
        <th>
            <select class='departureDate'>
                <option></option>
                <option data-id='0'>01/01/2015</option>
                <option data-id='1'>02/01/2015</option>
                <option data-id='2'>03/01/2015</option>
                <option data-id='3'>04/01/2015</option>
                <option data-id='4'>05/01/2015</option>
            </select>
        </th>
        <th>
            <select class='departureDuration'>
                <option></option>
                <option data-id='0'>1</option>
                <option data-id='1'>2</option>
                <option data-id='2'>3</option>
                <option data-id='3'>4</option>
                <option data-id='4'>5</option>
            </select>
        </th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr data-all='0,0,0'>
            <td class='city'>A</td>
            <td class='date'>01/01/2015</td>
            <td class='duration'>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-all='1,0,0'>
            <td class='city'>B</td>
            <td class='date'>01/01/2015</td>
            <td class='duration'>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-all='0,1,0'>
            <td class='city'>A</td>
            <td class='date'>02/01/2015</td>
            <td class='duration'>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-all='0,0,4'>
            <td class='city'>A</td>
            <td class='date'>01/01/2015</td>
            <td class='duration'>5</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

jQuery

```
var $city = $('.departureCity');
var $date = $('.departureDate');
var $dur = $('.departureDuration');

$('#trips select').on('change', function() {
    var array = [];
    array.city = $city.find('option:selected').data('id');
    array.date = $date.find('option:selected').data('id');
    array.dur = $dur.find('option:selected').data('id');
    console.log(array);
    if(typeof array.city === 'undefined') array.city = '[0-9]+';
    if(typeof array.date === 'undefined') array.date = '[0-9]+';
    if(typeof array.dur === 'undefined') array.dur = '[0-9]+';
    var regex = array.city+','+array.date+','+array.dur;
    $('#trips tbody tr').show();
    $('#trips tbody tr').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var data = $this.data('all');
        if(data.match(regex)) $this.show();
        else $this.hide();
    });

});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/nfLog6x8/

Comment: This is really interesting and well tough ! I think I'll do that. Thank you for having take your time to show me this !

Comment: You're welcome, it is new to me too! It was bugging me that I couldn't figure out how to do this with easy code, so I used Regex instead haha.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use AJAX to repopulate the table after each selection is changed. Then just output the table with php and refresh its container. This would be the PHP/AJAX way of doing it, but I think the jQuery way works fine as well

Comment: Just a comment to say how much you've helped me with my function :) 
The final result is beautiful ! I'll link it as soon as the pre prod is ready to be lunch.
Thanks again you shall got more up-vote just for this !

Comment: You're very welcome! I will likely use it at some point too. I thought your question was interesting. Your question should have more upvotes too